# With jQuery DataTables, how do I make the mouse cursor change over sortable column headers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In [DataTables examples](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html), I see that the mouse cursor changes to indicate a link when hovering above sortable column headers. However, I do not get the same effect in my own project. I configure DataTables like so (with theming by jQuery UI ThemeRoller):

```
$('#build-table').dataTable({
    'aaSorting': [[1, 'desc'], [0, 'asc'], [2, 'asc']],
    'bJQueryUI': true,
    });
```

How do I get the mouse cursor behaviour, when hovering above sortable column headers, of the DataTables demos?

**EDIT**

I know it's doable with CSS, but wondering if there's anything out of the box as the DataTable demos all work like this.

Comment: Using CSS, for example: cursor: pointer;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `dataTable()` specifically, but the easiest way is to give the sortable columns a class and use the CSS `cursor:pointer;` property to make the mouse indicate it is clickable.

Comment: From inspecting a DataTables demo, I found it's specified in the demo CSS, so this is the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The datatables demos all use [demo_table.css](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/css/demo_table.css) and this rule:

```
table.display thead th {
    padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer; /*This is what you want*/
    * cursor: hand;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following as CSS and you are good to go.

```
.sorting {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.sorting_asc {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.sorting_desc {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```